# Call external WFS Stored Query in ArcMap for desktop

Tags: arcgis, arcmap

I have set up a WFS compatible service to provide geo data from my application. I am using a couple stored queries to provide Features via an HTTP GET request and returning XML.

I want to consume this using the ArcGis desktop app (ArcMap), but I cannot figure out how to do this. I can find how to consume a stored query from an ArcGIS server (Catalog -> GIS Servers -> Add ArcGIS Server). I am not using a GeoData database that I can publish through ArcGIS to be consumed this way. I am just providing the ability to request the data using a WFS GetFeature StoredQuery call and returning data in a WFS compatible format (and passes the schema validation).

My request I am testing looks like this:

```
http://localhost/AWQMS/api/wfs?service=wfs&request=GetFeature&storedQuery_id=GetFeaturesByParameters&OrganizationIdentifiersCsv=BISHOP_PAIUTE_TRIBE_WQX
```

Can I consume this using ArcMap do display my features on the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ArcMap doesn't play well with WFS [out of the box](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/web-maps-and-services/adding-a-wfs-service-to-arcmap.htm):

> To use WFS and GML content in ArcGIS for Desktop, you need to install the Data Interoperability extension and add an Interoperability Connection to the WFS service.

But assuming you are licensed for the extension and [set up the interoperability connection](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/using-arccatalog/creating-an-interoperability-connection.htm), yes, you can consume it in ArcMap.

Comment: Thanks Erica. I do have a data interoperability connection set up. Right now it is able to get the capabilities document and determine my featureTypes and then performs the GetFeature request when I add the data to a layer. What I can't find is how I can use a Stored Query which, to my understanding of WFS, allows me to add whatever parameters I want (in my example the "OrganizationIdentifiersCsv" in order to return only the features that match my query. Any ideas on how to consume a Stored Query in ArcMap?